# How do I select a random index in a print statement python

Tags: python, indexing

I have this print statement and I want to select a random index from the list provided

```
print("{randint(1, 10)}".format(player_r1, player_r2, player_r3, player_r4, player_r5, player_r6, player_r7, player_r8, player_r9, player_r10))
```

Comment: The randint(1, 10) does not work

Comment: that means do you need to get random number from a list?

Comment: random.choice() can be used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code expressions inside strings are not evaluated, it's just text.

```
import random

print("{}".format(random.choice([player_r1, player_r2, player_r3, player_r4, player_r5, player_r6, player_r7, player_r8, player_r9, player_r10])))
```

Or something more readable:

```
players = [player_r1, player_r2, player_r3, player_r4, player_r5, player_r6, player_r7, player_r8, player_r9, player_r10]
print("{}".format(random.choice(players)))
```

Comment: Do i need to import anything for this to work? its not recognising "random"

Comment: Obviously, you need to import the `random` module.

Comment: Worked, Thanks alot

Comment: @TechDynasty then you should accept the answer (click the check-mark under the vote-score).